# Not able to access firestore database documents for list view and there is also a error with async querySnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database created manually which has a single collection called countries and then it has several documents under it now I am trying to retrieve data from there and show it in a list view with tiles but it is giving errors about querysnapshot and Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist.What do i do?

code which was working fine but I was able to access information from only one document

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('countries')
          .doc('nW9L4LGpn2MZVyiTyUII')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.. please wait..');
        return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data['name']),
            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data['cuisine']),
          );
        });
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

now when I try to access different document

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('countries')
            // .doc('nW9L4LGpn2MZVyiTyUII')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.hasError) return Text('has some error');
          if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            // if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.. please wait..');
            final list = querySnapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(list[index]['name']),
                  subtitle: Text(list[index]['cuisine']),
                );
              },
              itemCount: list.length,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this also throws a dart error which is

```
error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'. (undefined_operator at [vola1] lib\test.dart:26)
```

and the error it is throwing after this

```
error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'. (undefined_getter at [vola1] lib\test.dart:30)
```

I have recently started using firebase firestore am I not sure what to do about these errors.

Comment: change `final list = snapshot.data;` to `final list = snapshot.data.data();`, and other places where you have `snapshot.data` => `snapshot.data.data()`

Comment: also within your item builder, do not forget to specify the itemCount: List.length, so that you loop through until the end of the list.

Comment: i updated the code now but still there are these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the callback definition for your `builder`:

```dart
    builder: (context, snapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
    ...
    }
```

The definition for a StreamBuilder's `builder` is an [AsyncWidgetBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncWidgetBuilder.html) which take two arguments:

1. A BuildContext and,
2. A snapshot

So you should change your `builder` to the code below:

```dart
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
    ...
    }
```

This is also stated in the error message:

```
 The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>)'.
```

And to read the data, you need to get the list of `DocumentSnapshot` with the `.docs` getter on the `QuerySnapshot`. So you should update your code to this for the `list` variable:

```
final list = querySnapshot.data.docs;
```

Comment: I edited the code as u suggested and it still throws these errors I also edited the code in the question mentioned above. could you please check it once

Comment: I've updated my answer now. This line: `final list = querySnapshot.data.docs;`
 should remove the error.